# preg_match file url from jwplayer

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping, preg-match

I used simple HTML DOM Parser to get the html from a page.

Now I want to scrape the file URL from the `<script></script>` tags. This what I got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("ContainerFlashPlayer").setup({
        'autostart': 'true',
        'primary': 'html5',
        'flashplayer': '/images/embed/player.5.10.swf',
        'file':'/zxdfgdfr44444/afrah/Basem_elkerbelay/selawat/guivvahpasjp.mp3',
        'duration': '356.64975',
        'image': '/images/flashimg.png',
        'volume': '75',
        'height': '240',
        'width': '330',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'stretching': 'fill',
        'skin': '/images/embed/skin/shiavoice1.2.zip'
    }); 

</script>
```

Now I want to get the file url.
How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to fix the formatting, grammar, and some typos.

Comment: Thank you.And I'm sorry for my bad english. @EdCottrell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do...

```
<?php
$string = "jwplayer(\"ContainerFlashPlayer\").setup({

 'autostart': 'true',
 'primary': 'html5',
 'flashplayer': '/images/embed/player.5.10.swf',
 'file':'/zxdfgdfr44444/afrah/Basem_elkerbelay/selawat/guivvahpasjp.mp3',
 'duration': '356.64975',
 'image': '/images/flashimg.png',
 'volume': '75',
 'height': '240',
 'width': '330',
 'controlbar': 'bottom',
 'stretching': 'fill',
'skin': '/images/embed/skin/shiavoice1.2.zip' 

});";
preg_match("~^\s*'file'\s*:\s*'(.*?)',?\s*$~m", $string, $file);
echo $file[1];
```

Output:

> /zxdfgdfr44444/afrah/Basem_elkerbelay/selawat/guivvahpasjp.mp3

What does that regex say?

> `^` Start of the line
>
> `\s*` any number of whitespace characters
>
> Search for the following actual text `'file'`
>
> Again any number of whitespace characters with a colon separating it `\s*:\s*`
>
> A single quote then everything inbetween that and the next single quote `'(.*?)'`
>
> An optional comma, optional white space and then the end of the line `,?\s*$`
>
> The `m` after the closing delimiter is so the regex searches each line as its own line.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: its work fine but when i change `$string` to the html page ( `$html = file_get_html("http://www.shiavoice.com/play-uzuFX.html");` its giving me error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\sounds\savecontent.php on line 51`??

Comment: If you output the source of `$html` does it have the source you provided?

Comment: yes when I out put the $html I get the whole page with the code I provided in it.

Comment: thank you. I used file_get_contents and it worked.But why it didnt work with file_get_html from the simple HTML DOM Parser library? and thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure why the file_get_html wouldn't work. That function isn't available on my local PHP configuration so I can't really debug that issue to easily.